# How to detect URL changes in tabs.openWithOptions?

Tags: trigger.io

So I have the following code:

```
options = {
    url: "http://mywebsite.com/login/" + authService,
    pattern: "http://*mywebsite.com/complete/" + authService + "*",
  };
  forge.tabs.openWithOptions(options, function(data) {
    // We've logged in. Do something now
  }, function(data) {
    forge.logging.error("Error");
  });
```

The code works fine on the iPhone simulator, but the success callback doesn't get called in the Android emulator. It doesn't seem to register going to the redirect url from Oauth. In the emulator, it does load my redirect URL but it doesn't log that it does. This is what is logged in forge run:

```
[   INFO] I/Forge   (  393): Loading initial page in webview.

[   INFO] I/Forge   (  393): Application in focus, resuming webview.

[   INFO] D/Forge   (  393): Returning event: {"event":"internal.connectionStateChange","params":{"wifi":false,"connected":true}}

[   INFO] D/Forge   (  393): Native call "tabbar.hide" with task.params: {}

[   INFO] D/Forge   (  393): Returning: {"status":"success","callid":"2C1DB06C-9438-4AFD-841B-C2E3BBF8AA85"}

[   INFO] D/Forge   (  393): Native call "tabbar.addButton" with task.params: {"text":"Events","icon":"img/logo-forge.png"}

[   INFO] D/Forge   (  393): Native call "tabbar.addButton" with task.params: {"text":"Activity","icon":"img/logo-forge.png"}

[   INFO] D/Forge   (  393): Native call "tabbar.addButton" with task.params: {"text":"Me","icon":"img/logo-forge.png"}

[   INFO] D/Forge   (  393): Returning: {"content":"37F88F37-9A08-4541-8B1D-D7D08C2605D8","status":"success","callid":"37F88F37-9A08-4541-8B1D-D7D08C2605D8"}

[   INFO] D/Forge   (  393): Returning: {"content":"FFA69B04-006E-45CB-8BD7-A3CBB7E8403C","status":"success","callid":"FFA69B04-006E-45CB-8BD7-A3CBB7E8403C"}

[   INFO] D/Forge   (  393): Returning: {"content":"99681BEB-E79B-4309-B230-90B731A3DA61","status":"success","callid":"99681BEB-E79B-4309-B230-90B731A3DA61"}

[   INFO] D/Forge   (  393): Native call "internal.hideLaunchImage" with task.params: {}

[   INFO] D/Forge   (  393): Native call "tabbar.setActive" with task.params: {"id":"37F88F37-9A08-4541-8B1D-D7D08C2605D8"}

[   INFO] D/Forge   (  393): Returning: {"status":"success","callid":"23F0D9E1-5F63-4F6A-BFE0-14D674CDEB65"}

[   INFO] D/Forge   (  393): Native call "tabs.open" with task.params: {"url":"http://mywebsite.com/login/twitter","pattern":"^http://*mywebsite.com/complete/twitter.*$","title":"Sign in with Twitter"}

[   INFO] I/Forge   (  393): Displaying modal view.

[   INFO] I/Forge   (  393): subView load http://mywebsite.com/login/twitter/

[   INFO] I/Forge   (  393): subView load http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=TOKEN&oauth_callback=http%3A%2F%2Fmywebsite.com%2Fcomplete%2Ftwitter%2F
```

If I can't detect these URL changes consistently, is it possible to get the URL of the current tab at a point in time?

Note: I am using django-social-auth on my backend.

Comment: Could you attach the whole traceback? If the success callback isn't being called and "Error" isn't being logged then it looks like for some reason the pattern isn't matching.

Comment: One thing to try would be to navigate to the authorization url manually in both the iOS and Android mobile web browsers and check that you do in fact end up at the right success url

Comment: I've edited my post to include the full traceback. And looking at the mobile browsers, they do end up at the right success url. The success url is a redirect so maybe android doesn't catch it? I see it when I run Wireshark and the emulator.

Comment: Actually, I've fixed my issue. I ended up using a different URL for the pattern matching, but I think there was a difference in a trailing slash being included or not.